# InfoPath with Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, infopath, infopath2010

I have a new user account form that i have created using info path 2010 and am wondering if it is possible to get the account automatically created in active directory by being able to press an approve button that can only be used by people in a certain A.D group?

Comment: Can you elaborate your programming problem with showing your effort?

Comment: I have not written any code yet i am just wondering if it is possible to get the account created from an infopath form automatically.